# How to get status of Azure machine learning service pipeline run using Rest Api?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created an Azure Machine Learning Service Pipeline which i am invoking externally using its rest endpoint.
But i also need to monitor its run , whether it got completed or failed, periodically.
**Is there a methodinside a machine learning pipeline's rest endpoint, which i can hit to check its run status?**
I have tried the steps mentioned in the link here 
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/pipeline-batch-scoring/pipeline-batch-scoring.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting status of run, you can use REST APIs described here https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification/machinelearningservices/data-plane

Specifically you need https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/machinelearningservices/data-plane/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/preview/2019-08-01/runHistory.json

use this call to get run information including status:

> /history/v1.0/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspaceName}/experiments/{experimentName}/runs/{runId}/details

Comment: Thanks reznikob, that worked.
The exact api btw was:-
https://{location}.experiments.azureml.net/history/v1.0/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspaceName}/experiments/{experimentName}/runs/{runId}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Prashant!
The following endpoint works.

> https://{location}.experiments.azureml.net/history/v1.0/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspaceName}/experiments/{experimentName}/runs/{runId}

If it helps someone searching about this, here is some more information.

- Use the above endpoint with *GET* Method and Authorization *Bearer Access Token*

To obtain the access token, do the following.

> curl -X POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your-tenant-id}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Byour-tenant-id%7D/oauth2/token) 
> -d "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F&client_id={your-client-id}&client_secret={your-client-secret}" \

For more information, follow [How to Manage REST - Create, run, and delete Azure ML resources using REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-rest)